# Modify scale of Datadog metric

Tags: time, metrics, datadog

I have a time series presenting time values like this one:

[image]

I want to change the y-axis to represent hours instead of milliseconds, i.e. divide by 3600. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be achieved in two ways.

If you only want this logic to applied on this one graph, you can divide metric either using the UI editor and clicking advanced or using the JSON editor:

UI Editor: http://cl.ly/1c0K2O3P1E2K

Or JSON editor: https://help.datadoghq.com/hc/en-us/articles/203764925-How-do-I-use-arithmetic-for-my-time-series-data-

Alternatively, you can use the Metric Summary page to edit this metric's metadata and alter this metric's unit throughout the application as seen here: http://cl.ly/2x0Z290w2I3V

https://app.datadoghq.com/metric/summary

Hope this helps.  Also, you can reach out to support@datadoghq.com if you run into any other issues in the future.

Comment: Your link on JSON editor doesn't work, please update.

Comment: the links are no longer working, can you paste the content directly into the post?

Answer (score 0):

You can update metric unit to correct type on Metric details sidepanel of Metrics Summary page: https://docs.datadoghq.com/metrics/summary/#metric-unit.

[image: Screenshot of part of Metric details sidepanel]

You can get to Metrics Summary page by opening edit tab of your dashboard, clicking on your metric, and clicking on `Edit in Metrics Summary` link.

[image: Link to Edit in Metrics Summary]